# Dropping/Resetting Database using SQLITE3 Gem

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite

I'm a newbie to all of this. I'm running a project that uses the sqlite3 Ruby gem, but for some reason one of the table exists already. The project contains a ".sql" and ".db" file, among others.

How can you "view" or manipulate this database if it's running from a sqlite3 gem? Specifically, can you bundle exec rake, etc on it?

Answer (score 1):

From a Rails perspective Sqlite works the same as any other database such as PostreSQL or MySQL in that you can run rake tasks on it (e.g. rake db:create, or db:setup, db:reset, db:migrate, etc. all work as expected). You can also use the rails console to query for or insert new data via your active record model objects.

From a non-Rails perspective, Sqlite has various command-line and GUI interfaces that you can install to interact with a Sqlite database using SQL commands.